# NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getChannel()

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, nosuchmethoderror

I gone through java doucumntation of java mail [IdleManeger](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html).
Trying to implement forllwing example but got error with no such method.

I am on Linux, using java7 and javamail 1.5.
Following is the code.

```
openAccountWithImap();
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
final IdleManager idleManager = new IdleManager(session, es);
Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {
    @Override
    public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
        public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
        Folder folder = (Folder)ev.getSource();
        Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();
        System.out.println("Folder: " + folder + " got " + msgs.length + " new messages");
        try {
             // process new messages
            idleManager.watch(folder); // keep watching for new messages
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            // handle exception related to the Folder
        }
                        }
    });
idleManager.watch(folder);
```

And following is the stack stress.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getChannel()Ljava/nio/channels/SocketChannel;
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IdleManager.watch(IdleManager.java:201)
    at com.itrack.listener.EmailMessageListener.storeNotification(EmailMessageListener.java:99)
    at com.itrack.listener.EmailMessageListener.main(EmailMessageListener.java:41)
```

Not figure out what I am doing wrong. Please assist.

Comment: Make sure that jar used for compilation is also available on run-time.

Comment: @SnehalPatel, I added this jar in eclipse, is this possible diffent jar is used for run?

Comment: How are you packaging your application to run, and where are you running it?  In an application server?  It looks like you've got a mix of different versions of JavaMail.  What exactly did you add to your Eclipse project?